# Relative Confidence

Tags: confidence-interval

I am a land surveyor working on specifications for GPS control networks, and have some questions this forum may help me solve.
We typically measure many lines between points which are converted to 3D vectors, then thrown into a least squares adjustment program.  Some of these points are held as "fixed" meaning they already have known coordinates, and the un-fixed points are then given new coordinates.  After the least squares adjustment a report is generated that shows 95% error ellipses at the un-fixed points, and also a value referred to as 95% relative confidence error *between* each pair  of points.  There is general consensus that this relative confidence error is simply the square root of the sum of the squares of the 95% error at each pair of un-fixed points.  The main goal is to report what error a surveyor would expect at 95% when they measure between these two points with a method of higher accuracy than GPS.  Is this the proper relative confidence technique?  I've done some checks on sample data and it seems this method is overly confident.